# How can I get break on runtime exception(or error) in javascript (or ecmascript?)

Tags: javascript, debugging, runtime, break

How can I break on error?

I have a code:

```
throw new Error("Some error");
```

And I'm using most recent version of Web Inspector (Webkit) and Firebug(Mozilla). These tools catch and print the error, but does not break. May I don't know the how to. Please let me know how can I to do these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebKit you need to click this to enable break on error. If you click it again it will also break on warnings and clicking it again will disable it.

[alt text http://a.yfrog.com/img832/3580/screenshot20100723at101.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img832/3580/screenshot20100723at101.png)

Comment: Wow! This worked! Thanks! Webkit broke, but it does not print the error message until I click the continue button. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I don't think so. It stops execution right before the error, so the error is not printed yet.

Comment: Your image is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I redefined Error to get solution.

```
    var Error   =   function(v)
    {
        console.trace();
        console.debug(v);
    }
```

This solved my problem.